# Can Snowflake be used to mitigate application failure for business continuity?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like your opinions or experiences around the following possible solution idea. I know Snowflake is primarily a data analytics platform. But why could we not use it for some creative scenarios like business continuity?

**Problem**
Imagine an application that supports a critical business process. There is a risk that the application could become unavailable for an extended period. The application in this case is a SaaS solution by a reputable vendor, Salesforce. So it does not go down often. And when it does, they normally restore it in less than a day. But the business process is a critical medical logistics process - meaning if a transaction is delayed for a few days, lives may be lost.

**Background**
Our transaction volumes are moderate. We probably serve 25 new patients per day, with a few hundred interactions each day to support those. In the even of an outage, a subset of those might need immediate manual intervention to keep things moving. Others might be able to wait a couple of days.

We already use Snowflake to store replicas of the application's data. We use Looker to write analytics reports.

**Proposed Solution**
Write reports that expose critical data that may be needed if the primary application fails. Then, when the primary application fails, users can view reports using the latest replicated data to enable manual activities to keep things going until the primary application is restored to working order.
If data changes are needed, they must be written down somewhere and then applied to the application when its availability is restored

Comment: Why not expend the effort on making the application properly resilient with failover/failback, DR, etc. rather than trying  to hack together another solution?

Comment: thanks, @NickW. In my scenario, the application is a SaaS with a good reputation. It already has good failover. There is little we can do to improve it. But the business process is life-sensitive in the sense that we are supporting time-critical medical decisions and transporting therapies directly to patients. So even though the vendor is a highly reliable SaaS vendor, there are no guarantees. I am not proposing to build an alternative interaction application. Just provide reports with the latest information we had so we can do manual workarounds.

Comment: I updated the question to provide better context.

Answer (score 1):

Your only issue could be latency, as it is today Snowflake is not built for OLTP workloads, but OLAP workloads.

If the latency you get when running queries from Snowflake is fine then you have a valid use case.

Snowflake is used as an Application backend - particularly if the query is about historical analysis and latency is acceptable at a few seconds as opposed to immediate.

See: https://www.snowflake.com/workloads/data-applications/